# How to Link a Document in Alfresco using Apache Chemistry

Tags: alfresco, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I have just started `alfresco`, My requirement is to create a link of existing document to other folder using `apache chemistry` in `java`. I am using `alfresco-community-5` version. Please some one suggest me how to do thin. thank you

Comment: Do you meen to get the `file` + `folder` that already exists in your `alfresco`

Comment: No, suppose I have a file name xyz.txt in folder A. Now I want to link xyz.txt file into folder B using link. Actual content will be stay only on folder A but we can access it from folder B also.

Comment: Do you work with a database ???

Comment: thanx for response, no I am not working on database.

Comment: I've done that but i used a database to store the link to the document and you can do something like this

Comment: can you please share, how to do this using database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117944/discussion-between-rish-and-yagami-light).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is add a document to an additional folder. In CMIS speak this is called "multifiling". The Apache Chemistry web site has a [good example](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/guide.html#multi-filing-and-unfiling) showing how to check to make sure your repository supports multifiling (Alfresco does) and then how to add the document to an additional folder.

Be aware that if you do this in Alfresco and then attempt to use Alfresco Share your results from an end-user perspective may be unpredictable, so test thoroughly.

Comment: thnx for reply, my requirement is to create shortcut of document to other folder. I don't know it's possible or not. For example, same like we create shortcut of folder or file in windows machine.

Comment: Yes, multifiling the document into additional folders is how you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to simply build an association (relationship). You have an example behind a link Jeff posted.